# Error when accessing LocalDB from UWP: Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call

Tags: c#, uwp, entity-framework-core, localdb

I have an UWP application with an EFCore 2.1 datalayer which has to get data from a LocalDB, but I'm getting the following error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related
> or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
> SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
> that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
> allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50
> Local Database Runtime error occurred. Unexpected error occurred inside a LocalDB instance API method call. See the Windows Application
> event log for error details.

In the Windows Application event log, I have the following errors:

> - Windows API call CreateMutexW returned error code: 5. Windows system
>   error message is: Access is denied.
> - Unexpected error occurred while
>   trying to access the LocalDB instance registry configuration. See the
>   Windows Application event log for error details.
> - Windows API call
>   FormatMessageW returned error code: 1815. Windows system error message
>   is: The specified resource language ID cannot be found in the image
>   file.

Notes:

- I can connect to the LocalDB with SSMS.
- I have an API in .Net Core 3.1 which is using the exact same datalayer and connection string on the exact same LocalDB, but there's no error on this project and the data are correctly retrieved.
- The UWP application can connect correctly to a SQL Server or SQL Express DB with also the same datalayer: only the connection string is changed.

Comment: LocalDB requires named pipes. Maybe just use SQL Express instead?

Comment: @ErikEJ I think the opposite: looks like it's trying to use Shared Memory. Maybe switch to Named Pipes

Comment: @Charlieface I'm new to LocalDB, could you let me know how to switch to Named Pipes ? Thx

Comment: You prefix with `np` to force Named Pipes and `lpc` for Shared Memory `server=np:yourServerNameOrAddress` you also need to switch on Named Pipes in the Configuration Manager https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-or-disable-a-server-network-protocol?view=sql-server-ver15